# Inconsistent regex character classes in java

Tags: java, regex

How does Java handle receiving an inconsistent regex Pattern? I am trying this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-d[m-p][^d][m]]");
Matcher m = p.matcher("d");
System.out.println(m.matches());
```

for which I am receiving true. However, my character class contains [^d], so according to the regex, it shouldn't be a match. But since *d* is also contained in the pattern (*a-d*), the result to the match is positive. So, how is the parsing of the pattern done? Wouldn't it be better if it threw an exception?

Comment: Why inconsistent? It is quite ok for Java.

Comment: I said inconsistent because I included and excluded letter "d" in the pattern.

Comment: Though correct a "smart" compiler with a `-verbose` option might tell `"[m] option superfluous, [^d] has no effect - did you mean "&&[^d]"?`. Best is some tool like **FindBugs**, marking such flaws.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior is correct and [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

> Character classes may appear within other character classes, and may be composed by the union operator (`implicit`) and the intersection operator (`&&`).

Also see [Java *Character Classes* reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html):

> `[a-d[m-p]]`  `a` through `d`, **or** `m` through `p`: `[a-dm-p]` *(union)*

So, the pattern matches:

- `[` - start of character class
- `a-d` - `a` through `d` **OR**
- `[m-p]` - `m` through `p` **OR**
- `[^d]` - not `d` **OR**
- `[m]` - `m`
- `]` - end of the character class.

As `d` gets matched with `a-d` the match is returned.

If you want to match a range of symbols *except* some of them, you need *subtraction*:

```
[a-d[m-p][m]&&[^d]]
```

This regex won't match `d` since the `a-d` range is now "tempered" with `&&[^d]` and will no longer match `d`.

Comment: True, completely forgot that the union was a simple "OR". Thanks

Comment: Yes. Just FYI: you can quickly visually test the regex at http://www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/java-visual-regex-tester/